# sed: interpolating variables in timestamp format

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to use sed to extract all the lines between two specific strings from a file.
I need to do this on a script and my two strings are variables.
The strings will be in a sort of time stamp format, which means they can be something like:
`2014/01/01` or `2014/01/01 08:01`

I was trying with something like:

```
sed -n '/$1/,/$2/p' $file
```

or even

```
sed -n '/"$1"/,/"$2"/p' $file
```

with no luck, tried also to replace `/` as delimiter with `;`.

I'm pretty sure the problem is due to the `/` and blank in input variables, but I can't figure out the proper syntax.

Comment: What's the error/problem specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to use alternate regex delimiters is:

> \ **c** regexp **c**
>
> > Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The **c** may be any character.

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses

So, pick one of

```
sed -n '\@'"$1"'@,\@'"$2"'@p' "$file"
sed -n "\\@$1@,\\@$2@p" "$file"
sed -n "$( printf '\@%s@,\@%s@p' "$1" "$2" )" "$file"
```

or awk

```
awk -v start="$1" -v end="$1" '$0 ~ start {p=1}; p; $0 ~ end {p=0}' "$file"
```

---

From the *first* $1 to the *last* $2:

```
sed -n "\\@$1@,\$p" "$file" | tac | sed -n "\\@$2@,\$p" | tac
```

This prints from the first $1 to the end, reverses the lines, prints from the *first* $2 to the new end, and reverses the lines again.

An example: from the first "5" to the last "7"

```
$ set -- 5 7
$ seq 20 | sed -n "\\@$1@,\$p" | tac  | sed -n "\\@$2@,\$p" | tac
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
```

Comment: You want `@p` not `/p`.

Comment: Just one more question, te output stop at the first $2 encounter, given i have multiple $2 lines is there an elegant way to tell sed to print all of them? jsut to clarify i can do in multiple command summing the output was just wondering if i can do with a single line command, sorry i'm old school i'm greedy in line of code :)

Comment: Do you mean all of the $1-$2 ranges, or from the first $1 to the last $2?

Comment: From the first $1 to the last $2 currently (like i was expecting) I get from the first $1 to the first $2. it is a not a big issue because with 2 line of code more i get the same just wondering if i have an option in sed which allow this all in one command

Comment: No, since sed is line oriented, there can be no way of knowing when you see a string if it is going to be the last one. I'll provide another option in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Try using **double quotes** instead of single ones.

```
sed -n "/$1/,/$2/p" $file
```

Comment: To expand on csiu's answer: Cris, you probably want to learn more about how your shell handles information inside single or double quotes differently. Here is one good resource: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.